# axios extra property data in response and error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, axios

In the axios's response we do

```
axios.get(url).then(response => console.log(response.data.our_response)).catch(err => err.data.our_error)
```

can I write a global helper function to assume data property is always present? so that I write

```
try {
  const { result } = await axios.get(url) // instead of const { data: {result}) = await axios.get(url)
} catch(err) {
 console.log(err) //instead err.data.err
}
```

it's tedious if I have to access to the data properly on each api.

Comment: You can use an Axios Response interceptor: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: @aprouja1 I know that I'm just curious why axios make it compulsory to have a data property, I suspect they will be response.somethingelse.myData hmm

Comment: Because you may just want headers or something else

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , that  only is standard  formal by developer like why JSON look that with ｛｝ , you can try console. log (respons).